# Embedding Dynamic Images in VF Page that renders as PDF

Tags: visualforce, pdf

I would like to know how can we embed an image that's got as a response from an external service. It works fine in a VF page but when `renderAs="PDF"` is given, the image is broken since the page renders before the response is got from the external server.

**Edit :**

This is what I've tried and its working. I send a http request to the external server and i get a response which I store as an attachment using `response.getBodyAsBlob()` and set the ContentType to 'png' and save it.

Now that it's working I've another doubt. Since the call to external server might get delayed response, if I send the call out in constructor or 'action parameter in `<apex:page>`', the page will take time to load and render as PDF.

Since the delay is unavoidable, is there a way to set a kind of timer in apex to limit the time the request can wait for response?

Comment: Check http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/23/is-it-possible-to-use-images-in-visualforce-generated-pdfs-which-are-not-static, maybe it's worth playing with your Remote Site Settings

Comment: Have you tried to use the `action` parameter of the `apex:page` to invoke the service before the page is rendered?

Comment: Is there any Javascript involved on the page? JS doesn't execute when rendering as PDF.

Comment: @Sergrey : That's a great suggestion.

Comment: @Daniel: No, there is isn't any.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regarding your edit to the question: yes, you can specify callout timeouts.

http://wiki.developerforce.com/page/Apex_Web_Services_and_Callouts#Additional_Considerations

```
// SOAP callouts - code generated from WSDL will have timeout_x variable.
// Modify it in said class (for all callouts) or only in controller of your specific page.
docSample.DocSamplePort stub = new docSample.DocSamplePort();
stub.timeout_x = 2000; // timeout in milliseconds

// REST callouts
HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
req.setTimeout(2000); // timeout in milliseconds
```

To be honest I've never had broken images from callouts (maybe they were completing before the timeout). I'd expect the PDF rendering engine to wait (straightforward img tag like in https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/10713/799).

If you're hitting timeouts then either leave your updated code as is or maybe split it into 2 actions "fetch image, store as attachment" and "compile PDF with latest image"?